# Bearer Authorization токен подменяется на Basic токен при отправке запроса из мобильного браузера

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

Всем привет, есть странная проблема. Я создал инстанс axios, и повесил интерцептор на все запросы, чтобы добавлять токен авторизации:

```
const $api = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  baseURL: API_URL,
})

$api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  if (config && config.headers && localStorage.getItem('token')){
    config.headers["Authorization"] = `bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
    config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
  }
  return config
})
```

При отправке из браузера на десктопе все окей:

[image: Запрос на десктопе]

При отправке с мобильного устройства (Браузеры Chrome / Safari):

[image: Запрос в мобилке]

Использовал XCode для эмуляции мобильной версии сайта + proxyman чтобы посмотреть что уходит в запросе

Comment: скорее всего у вас нет токена в localStorage, так что посылается Basic, который стоит при входе на сайт

Comment: `if (config && config.headers && localStorage.getItem('token')){` я имею ввиду, что по какой-то причине вы не входите в этот условный оператор. скорее всего нет токена. может быть нет config.headers

Comment: Токен точно есть, я ставил alert(config.headers["Authorization"]) внутри условия, и он выводил нужный header, но отправляет все равно Basic

Comment: видимо, под ios побеждает Basic. попробуйте послать в другом заголовке, например x-access-token или отключите Basic-авторизацию

Comment: А как отключить Basic авторизацию? Я ее искусственно не включал

Comment: но у вас на домене (со скрина) стоит запрос логина пароля (basic auth) от веб-сервера )))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61968100/4496422

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Если у вас сложилось понимание проблемы и появился опыт решения проблемы, напишите ответ, пожалуйста. Это будет полезно для базы знаний.

Comment: Ну скажем так, победить базовый токен в поле Authorization не получилось, за то получилось прокидывать токен в другом заголовке, например в X-Access-Token